# Return value from text entry to some other class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get return values from tkinter window where i am entering text values,I want those text values to be returned so that I can capture those and send as input to other class methods.

I am able to print those captured values but not able to return them. I am very new to python

```
from tkinter import *


class gui_cls:
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.master=args[0]
        self.delete = StringVar()
        self.insert = StringVar()
        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.var3 = IntVar()


    def vergui(self):
        Delete = self.delete.get()
        insertversions = self.insert.get()
        prog = self.var1.get()
        print(Delete)
        print(insertversions)
        if prog:
            print("levels")
        else:
            pass

        label_0 = Label(self.master, text="Adaptive", width=20, font=("bold", 20))
        label_0.place(x=40, y=53)

        label_1 = Label(self.master, text="Delete Versions", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
        label_1.place(x=30, y=130)
        entry_1 = Entry(root, textvar=self.delete)
        entry_1.place(x=200, y=130)

        label_2 = Label(self.master, text="Insert Versions", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
        label_2.place(x=30, y=180)
        entry_2 = Entry(self.master, textvar=self.insert)
        entry_2.place(x=200, y=180)



        label_3 = Label(self.master, text="Reload", width=20, font=("bold", 10))
        label_3.place(x=30, y=230)
        var2 = IntVar()
        Checkbutton(self.master, text="Levels", padx=5, variable=self.var1).place(x=190, y=230)
        Checkbutton(self.master, text="Accounts", padx=20, variable=var2).place(x=250, y=230)

        label_4 = Label(self.master, text="Note: Please seperate versions by comma(,)", fg='red', font=("bold", 13)).place(x=30, y=280)
        Button(self.master, text='Finish', width=20, bg='brown', fg='white', command=self.vergui).place(x=200, y=350)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("Adaptive")
gui_cls(root).vergui()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Current you created an instance of the class on the fly. You can first define a variable for the instance of the class, and then call the methods separately:

```
#gui_cls(root).vergui()
gui = gui_cls(root)
gui.vergui()
```

Then you can access the class attributes anytime.

```
print (gui.delete.get())
print (gui.var1.get())
...
```

Comment: root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.title("Adaptive")
gui=gui_cls(root)
gui.vergui()
print(gui.delete.get())
root.mainloop()

Comment: not able to get the text value to a variable so that i can pass that value to other class

Comment: There is nothing in the variable when you print right after you create it.

Comment: i did y=gui.delete.get() then tried printing y it does not print any thing

Comment: You need to understand how it works. You first create an instance of the class by `gui = gui_cls(root)`. At this point, the text variable is empty so no matter how you `print` it right after, it will always be empty. What you need to do is to type in something in your `entry` field, and then trigger a function (possibly a button) to print the value at that point, or have some other function that calls `gui.delete.get()` AFTER the entry field is filled.

Comment: I got your point i did create insance. i am able to print but my issue is that i need to capture that value in entry and pass that to another class method  which take this as input..

Comment: Why do you need to capture the value? Just have the other class method read the value directly when needed.

Comment: Thats what i did rather than capturing..I am just passing that calue to other class theod.. Thank you very much for all your help....